# How to find the top 10 words from a given string at any given point of time. Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Lets say I have a string `s` and words are keep on adding to the string at any given point of time. Now I have to maintain top 10 reoccurring words at any given point of time.

My approach is I have a created a dictionary with key value pair as shown below.

```
dic = {}
for i in s:
   if i in dic:
      dic[i] +=1
   else:
      dic[i] = 1
```

now I want to maintain the frequency of the top 10 words in the above dictionary. 
possible ways through which I can perform the above action are

1. I can sort the dictionary after every iteration but it will result in the high complexity as dictionary may contains millions of records.
2. I can use the feature of counter or collections but I don't want to use any inbuilt function.

I want the above program to work in linear time. I know the above question has been asked before but I was not able to find the linear solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I am able to achieve what I was asking.

```
file = open('read.txt','r')
text = file.read().split()
word_cout = {}
top_words = {}
for i in text:
    if i in word_cout:
        word_cout[i] +=1
    else:
        word_cout[i] = 1
    if i not in top_words:
        for key in top_words.copy():
            if top_words[key] < word_cout[i]:
                top_words.pop(key)
                top_words[i] = word_cout[i]
                break
    if(len(top_words) < 10):
        top_words[i] = word_cout[i]

# print(word_cout)
print((top_words))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to sort the entire dict every time.  Just check whether the incremented value is now larger than the existing 10th largest value.

Comment: What if 10th largest value is incremented? You will need to check it up to the top.

Comment: If the incremented value is already in the top 10, nothing needs to change, because it is still in the top 10.  Even if you want to sort it within the top 10, that's O(1) each time, because you're only sorting the top 10, not the rest, so O(N) overall.

Comment: Yes, but it might become #9, so you will need to swap #9 and #10. Agree, it is still O(1)

Comment: @JohnZwinck That is my question, how can I keep the top 10 value sorted. I can keep the track of 10th position but how? can you explain with the help of code because that is what I am looking for.

Comment: @NikhilGupta: Just sort them.  Sorting 10 numbers is O(1).  I'm not sure what you mean by "how."  You can use bubble sort for example.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It would be very helpful if you can write the code of sorting the top 10 value of dictionary.